# Android _ The import android.support.v7.graphics cannot be resolved?

Tags: android, android-library

I add in my project `appcompat_v7` but I can't `import` :

```
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
```

What can I do ?

I see my `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` in this `jar` the package `android-support-v7.appcompat` is empty.How I can get sub `classes` ?

Comment: did you just add the jar file or the whole project?

Comment: I add all of project.

Comment: You need to import Palette lib separately and add to build path of your project.

Comment: How I can get `Palette lib `

Comment: In your sdk\extras\android\support\v7 folder. @JIM

Comment: There is just `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` and `android-support-v4.jar` that I added .

Comment: @JIM You need to add android-support-v7-palette.jar as well.

Comment: @JIM Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: @ Pooja , yes . Thanks . Response this question for vote.

Comment: I posted answer @JIM.Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add android-support-v7-palette.jar to your project and add it to build path.

or add the dependency into the app **gradle** file (latest version)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0'
```

And if you are using Android X:

```
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 18):

use this in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you use a version within the **compileSdkVersion**

For example for:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
```

you use:

`implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.x.x'`

Answer (score 0):

V26.0.2 is a bug for graphics, Use these upgraded dependency :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```